# How can i find if some image file is present in webapp directory or not dynamically?

Tags: jakarta-ee

suppose i m trying to find some image file is present in the web app but don't know the real path i.e. im having absolute path how do i get that path???

javax.servlet.servletcontext.getrealpath("");

is not working for me..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try using getRealPath like this

```
ServletContext context = session.getServletContext();
String realContextPath = context.getRealPath(request.getContextPath());
```

also , weblogic for example has a property named

```
<show-archived-real-path-enabled>true</show-archived-real-path-enabled>
```

that needs to be set to true in order for getrealpath to work,
http://rocksolutions.wordpress.com/2010/07/15/servletcontext-getrealpath-is-cause-problems-on-weblogic/